# Stop executing remaining macros if recordset.EOF is TRUE

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA code which has the following function. Of course there are other subs/ functions based on the recordSet which are used to populate the different spreadsheets in the workbook.

**Issue:** When the recordSet is Empty then a run-time error '13' Type: mismatch comes up. How can I add to this code to check if empty then stop populating the sheet.

```
Function GetSqlResultsAsArray(qry As String) As Variant
    
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim recordSet As ADODB.recordSet
    
    'connection string here
    conn.Open ConnectionString:=""
    
    Set recordSet = conn.Execute(qry)
    If Not recordSet.EOF And Not recordSet.BOF Then
         GetSqlResultsAsArray = recordSet.GetRows
    End If
    conn.Close

End Function
```

The next relevant code is: I want to stop resultsArray getting populated if the above code returns empty or null to void the Run-time error '13'. I do not know how to amend the below to do this.

```
Private Sub GetResultsData()

    'sub used to bring back a recordset with all results data based on the user criteria slected
    
    resultSql = GetResultSqlStatement(customer, product, startDate, endDate, productType)
    
    productSql = GetProductSqlStatement(product, customer, startDate, endDate)
    
   
    
    Dim resultsArray() As Variant
    
    resultsArray = GetSqlResultsAsArray(resultSql)
    
    resultsArray = TransposeArray(resultsArray)

    'Format data
    
    wsData.Range("A2").Resize(lr + 1, lc + 1).Value = resultsArray
    wsData.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(1, 1), wsData.Cells(lr + 2, lc + 1)), , xlYes).Name = "DataTable"
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your array to a parameter and change your ADO function to a boolean.

```
Function GetSqlResultsAsArray(qry As String, ResultsArray()) As Boolean
    
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim recordSet As ADODB.recordSet
    
    'connection string here
    conn.Open ConnectionString:=""
    
    Set recordSet = conn.Execute(qry)
    
    If Not recordSet.EOF And Not recordSet.BOF Then
        GetSqlResultsAsArray = True
        ResultsArray = recordSet.GetRows
    End If
    conn.Close

End Function
```

Then you can capture whether there are any results in the calling procedure by testing the value of HasRecords.

```
HasRecords = GetSqlResultsAsArray(resultSql, resultsArray)

If HasRecords Then
     resultsArray = TransposeArray(resultsArray)
    'Format data
    wsData.Range("A2").Resize(lr + 1, lc + 1).Value = resultsArray
    wsData.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(1, 1), 
    wsData.Cells(lr + 2, lc + 1)), , xlYes).Name = "DataTable"
End If
```

Or you can skip the HasRecords variable.

```
If GetSqlResultsAsArray(resultSql, resultsArray) Then
     resultsArray = TransposeArray(resultsArray)
    'Format data
    wsData.Range("A2").Resize(lr + 1, lc + 1).Value = resultsArray
    wsData.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(1, 1), 
    wsData.Cells(lr + 2, lc + 1)), , xlYes).Name = "DataTable"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks I edited the first code as suggested. However I am struggling with where to insert the HasRecords code in the second (Private Sub GetResultsData()) code. Can you help?

Comment: I added code at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: This has worked beautifully. I really appreciate your help with this coding.